# Javascript divide data show per 10 data then another set to the right column

Tags: javascript

How to divide column table per 10 data then next data set to the right column?

```
$("#Button50").click(function(){ 
    var pemenang_undian=new Array();
    var database = openDatabase("undian","1.0", "Contact Manager", 200000); 
    database.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM undian', [], function (tx, results) {
          var len = results.rows.length, i;
          for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            pemenang_undian.push(results.rows.item(i).name);
          }
        pemenang_undian=shuffle(pemenang_undian);
        document.getElementById("hasil").innerHTML= 'Pemenang 50 Peserta<br>';
            for (var j=0;j<50;j++)
            {
                tx.executeSql('delete from undian where no = '+pemenang_undian[j]);
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO pemenang_undian (no, name,time) VALUES ('+pemenang_undian[j]+', "'+pemenang_undian[j]+'", "50x1")');
                document.getElementById("hasil").innerHTML = document.getElementById("hasil").innerHTML + ("<td>"+pemenang_undian[j]+"</td>");
            }

        });
        pemenang_undian= [];

        document.getElementById("Button50").disabled=true;
        setTimeout(function() {document.getElementById("Button50").disabled=false;},5000);
    });
    });
```

HTML

```
<table id="hasil"></table>
```

The current, data will show with break.

[image]

What I want is:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help:

```
//Get your data into one variable like below
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
let count = 0;
let array_new = []
let final_arr = []

// Seperate data into 10 number of blocks.
for(let i = 0; i< arr.length; i++){
    count++;
    array_new.push(arr[i])
    if (count%10 == 0) {
        final_arr.push(array_new)
        array_new = []
    }
}

//Get data that will generate rows, rows will combine into one array.
for (var i in final_arr) 
{
   console.log("row " + i);
   for (var j in final_arr[i]) 
     {
      console.log(" " + final_arr[i][j]);
     }
}
console.log(final_arr) // This array will have your data into chunks.

//Now append data in html tag for generate column.
var htmlStr = "<tbody>";
for(let i=0; i < final_arr.length; ++i) {
    htmlStr += "<tr>";
    htmlStr += "<td>" + final_arr[i] + "</td>";
    htmlStr += "</tr>";
}
htmlStr += "</tbody>"

console.log(htmlStr) //append this string into your div using jQuery/JS
```

Comment: When will you get data? Starting from 167 to 128?

Comment: When I click button "Generate 50 Pemenang" then it will display random number

Comment: So store that number in arr and then paste above code in a script. In the last append htmlstr in div tag to view output on the browser.

Comment: Could you please let me know how to do that?

Comment: Define array on js, on the click of button call JS function and write code to get that data and use push method to push data into an array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157427/discussion-between-harsh-patel-and-hidayurie-dave).